# Why is -2 an answer for $\frac{|x+3|+x}{x+2} > 1$?

Tags: inequality, modular-arithmetic, rational-functions

> In the inequality $\frac{|x+3|+x}{x+2} > 1$, by doing sign chart method the answer I am getting is $x \in (−5,−2)\cup(−1,\infty)$

But the [graph in Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) shows that it should be $x \in (−5,−2]\cup(−1,\infty)$ with solid line on -2 but dots on -5 and -1

[Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%7Cx%2B3%7C%2Bx%29%2F+%28x%2B2%29+%3E+1) appears to be on my side though, as seen in the interval notation at the bottom

Am i reading it wrong or is Desmos wrong?

Comment: Well, The statement $\frac {|2+3|+2|}{2+2} = \frac 74 > 1$ isn't it?

Comment: @Fleablood I think he wanted to say -2

Comment: @fleablood For about 5 seconds i thought "wait you are right", then I remembered it's -2... meaning the denominator would become a 0, right? so shouldn't there be dotted lines on -2 as well?

Comment: Desmos just does not draw points of discontinuity, that's all. Draw for example $\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}+1$, clearly the function is not defined in $x=1$, but you don't see that in a graph.

Comment: @RossMillikan oh yes thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

$-2$ is not a solution.  You cannot compute the left side at $x=-2$ because of the division by $0$.